# Listview Adapter with SQLite Query's

Tags: android, performance, sqlite, listview, android-listview

I have a quick performance question; I have a ListView adapter which populates the listview and I open my sqlite database and close it at the end of populating the view and I populate some information about the list row from the SQLite database. I have noticed a serious performance hit with doing this mainly when scrolling which makes sense. I'm wondering how I can improve the performance of scrolling. I query the database about 3 times.

```
Database db = new Database(context);
db.open();
viewHolder.first.setText(db.queryFirst());
viewHolder.second.setText(db.querySecond());
viewHolder.third.setText(db.queryThird());
db.close();
```

Should I keep a reference to DB as an instance variable and just open and close when I query or how should I go about this?

Comment: I normally open the db in onCreate and close it in onDestroy.

Comment: I could have possible concurrency Issues as I have some services running that need access to the DB.

Comment: Did the service write to db.

Comment: why don't you use simpleCursorAdapter?

Comment: @HoanNguyen the service could possibly write to the DB it depends. As well I need to Query states more so in the database not just get information for specific rows to map to View's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm wondering how I can improve the performance of scrolling. I query the database about 3 times.

I recommend querying the database once for the whole adapter.  Currently you are sending three queries for each row and none of them are cached.  Reading from the drive is a slow process, Cursors are designed to fetch a large amount of data very efficiently and CursorAdapters are designed to use the least resources possible.  Using one Cursor and a CursorAdapter will allow users to scroll without noticing any performance loss.

Comment: You are correct I have now batched my queries and the Loading delay is gone. I had to take a step back and examine my overall logic thank's for the great answer though!

Answer (score 0):

There is also a library called ORMLite which allows you to manipulate database quite easily and you get back a list, which means you load the array first and you don't have any scrolling performance issue. This in combination with lazy loading sections of the database will allow you to seamlessly increase the performance of the scroll.